# Make my mongoDB collect data at a certain time of day every day?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm building a weather app that is scraping data from a particular site, however at certain time in the day the data becomes inaccurate because of the way I have to scrape the data. If i could collect the data at a certain time every day this wouldn't be an issue.

Is there a way for my Meteor server to go out and collect new data at 1 in the morning each day and store the info in a mongo database that i can use throughout the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the percolate:synced-cron package.

https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron

Using that you could do something like:

```js
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Scrape weather data',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('at 1:00 am' );
  },
  job: function() {
    // 
    // scraping code
    //
    WeatherData.insert(scrapedData); //insert to MongoDB Collection

  }
});

SyncedCron.start();
```

Comment: This looks awesome, does the parser actually accept something as informal at 'at 1:00 am'? Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes, it uses the later.js library for scheduling which is very flexible as to how you specify recurrences.  check out the full docs here http://bunkat.github.io/later/

Comment: Perfect! Will get to work on this now, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Also there is a plain-javascript solution based on `setTimeout` function:

```js
function updateWeather() {
  // Update weather logic
}

/**
 * @returns {Number} ms till next day's 1 am
 */
function computeMsToNextWeatherUpdate() {
  const tomorrow = new Date();

  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  tomorrow.setHours(13); // 1 am
  tomorrow.setMinutes(0);
  tomorrow.setSeconds(0);

  return tomorrow.getTime() - Date.now();
}

function startWeatherUpdater() {
  updateWeather();

  setTimeout(startWeatherUpdater, computeMsToNextWeatherUpdate());
}

startWeatherUpdater();
```

Comment: This does not seem to take into consideration if the process fails.

Comment: My solution is primitive and is acceptable for apps with one instance only. If process fails and then restarts, weather will be updated automatically on startup. If you have several instances of the app with one shared database, then you should use something like synced-cron. I just show that there are options.